# Replaying Kinect data in a unit test

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I have recorded Kinect skeleton streams using the Kinect Toolbox's KinectRecorder class. I would like to replay the **entire** recorded file in a unit test using the KinectReplay class from the Kinect Toolbox. The recordings are added to my test project as embedded resources (probably not relevant but as an explanation of the code below).

The problem I am facing is that the KinectReplay class (specifically the ReplaySystem class) uses the Task Parallel library of C# to playback the skeleton frames. Without any modifications this means that my unit test immediately returns from a call to KinectReplay.Start().

No modifications to Kinect Toolbox:

```
[Test]
public void CanPlaybackDataInNunitTest()
{
    Type thisType = this.GetType();
    Stream resourceStream =
        thisType.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
        thisType.Namespace +".TestDataFiles.testfile.replay");
    KinectReplay kinectReplay = new KinectReplay(resourceStream);

    kinectReplay.SkeletonFrameReady += (sender, args) =>
        { //breakpoint gets set on this brace, never hit
            //test
        };
    kinectReplay.Start();

    // ...
}
```

I have tried: adding a "ReplayFinished" .net event to the KinectReplay class, adding an AutoResetEvent to the KinectReplay class, and (shown below) a hybrid solution using event handlers and WaitHandles:

```
public void CanPlaybackDataInNunitTest()
{
    Type thisType = this.GetType();
    Stream resourceStream =
        thisType.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
        thisType.Namespace +".TestDataFiles.testfile.replay");
    KinectReplay kinectReplay = new KinectReplay(resourceStream);

    // Initialize a wait handle to know when replay ends
    AutoResetEvent isFinishedWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    kinectReplay.SkeletonFrameReady += (sender, args) =>
        { // breakpoint here, never hit
            //test
        };

    kinectReplay.Start();

    // subscribe to a new event i added to the KinectReplay class
    // This event is invoked when the IsFinished property becomes true
    kinectReplay.ReplayFinished += (o, a) =>
        {
            isFinishedWaitHandle.Set();
        };

    // the unit test will block here and will not return until the 5 minute timeout
    // I know that skeleton data is present within two seconds in the replay data
    isFinishedWaitHandle.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0));

    // ....
}
```

If it is not realistic to use the KinectToolbox for the goal of exercising algorithms in unit tests with playback data, I will consider other solutions!

Comment: where you able to get this to work?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I able to play back the streams in my unit tests by modifying the Kinect Toolbox code. I will add it to my list to put the code on github in the near future.

Comment: how do you mock the kinectSensor?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Mocking the sensor is not neccessary if you capture all information about the stream you are interested in including the floor plane and other things.

Comment: I see. I read that in order to record you need a Kinect-enabled app. Do they mean ANY app (including the ones on the toolkig browser) or MY app?  (I want to record for my test cases)

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I used my app in the past, but it seems like any app that connects to the sensor will work.

Comment: i see, thank you very much. By any chance do you have a source coded app I could read test cases from?